# ViewPager2 drag

Tags: android, drag

How to make viewpager2 only drag to the previous page or next page? Now it can be dragged up and down infinitely.
Just like TikTok's video playlist, the drag up and down effect is the same. Unprocessed viewpager2 can be dragged up and down indefinitely

```
vp2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels){
super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
  if(Math.abs(position-currentPosition)>1){
    vp2.setUserInputEnabled(false) 
  }else{
    vp2.setUserInputEnabled(true) 
  }
}
```

setUserInputEnabled is too crude because it terminates the sliding event...

Answer (score 0):

since you getting crash on registeronpagechangecsllback try :

```
class VerticalViewPager2(context: Context) : ViewPager2(context) {
override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    // Swap x and y to enable vertical swiping
    val swappedEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(event)
    swappedEvent.setLocation(event?.y ?: 0F, event?.x ?: 0F)
    val handled = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swappedEvent)
    swappedEvent.recycle()
    return handled
}

override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
    // Swap x and y to enable vertical swiping
    val swappedEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(event)
    swappedEvent.setLocation(event?.y ?: 0F, event?.x ?: 0F)
    val handled = super.onTouchEvent(swappedEvent)
    swappedEvent.recycle()
    return handled
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll to the next and previous page without using `setUserInputEnabled`, you can use `ItemTouchHelper`. As you know, ViewPager2 is built on **Recylerview**.

```
val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, 
    ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN) {
  
    override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, 
        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
        
        if(direction == ItemTouchHelper.UP){
            //next 
            if (pager.currentItem < (pager.adapter.itemCount - 1)) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(pager.currentItem + 1, true)
            }
        } else {
            //previous 
            if(pager.currentItem > 0){
                pager.setCurrentItem(pager.currentItem - 1, true)
            }
        }
    }
})
itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(yourViewPager.recyclerView)
```